# Django in IIS not loading Static Files

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, iis

I successfully integrated django in IIS 7.5 (server loads django1.6.5 using python2.7) but it doesn't load static files(CSS, JS), when I run `manage.py runserver` static files were loaded though. Am I missing something. I followed this tutorial in YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXbfHtAvubc. Thanks!

Comment: Did you run python manage.py collectstatic? Are the files not getting put where you expect or is IIS just not sharing them

Comment: @Foon i'd run collectstatic but still not working, do i have to setup something on iis?

Comment: I haven't used IIS with Django; with apache, you generally do have some configuring although it can be as simple as defining your static root within the apache html directory (/var/www/html by default on at least Redhat systems) and then fixing permissions.  Is your IIS hosting a static html directory?

Answer (score 0):

That video works great on my static file serving. Here is my environment: Python 2.7 Django 1.7 on Windows Server IIS 7.5

If you stick on steps, there shouldn't be any problem. Make sure you remove "Django Handler" in staticapp which is @ 17:51 on that video. And check whether there is a static file handler in handler mappings. After you check your steps and make sure everything is right, you may try another way below to serve static file.

---

You may add a virtual directory to serve static file.
[[How to fetch static CSS files with django on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312590/how-to-fetch-static-css-files-with-django-on-iis][1])